# Webservice method to call a url

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I have a webservice, it has its wsdl and everything works fine when I make a call to my web service.

What I want to do now is call a url from somewhere within my web service method. In c# code behind I can do it something like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Insurance.aspx?fileno1=" + txtFileNo1.Text + "&fileno2=" + txtFileNo2.Text + "&docid=" + Convert.ToString(GridView1.SelectedDataKey[2]));
```

but the Response.Redirect option is not available on the asmx page.

Is something like this possible? If so then would be grateful in anybody can show me how. I've tried searching everywhere but can only find about calling a web service or calling a webs ervice inside another web service but no such topics on calling a url from within your web service. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call a url"? Do you mean redirect the user? If so, you can access the current Response in your web service by calling `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(...)`

Comment: Call a url like "www.insuranceini.com/insurance.aspx?fileno1="+txtfileno1 my client calls my webservice which then makes a call to another one of my Apis like the link above which processes the data the client is sending me.

Comment: @Dave Zych do you suppose the HttpContext you've mentioned will work for my scenario just clarified above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Response.Redirect` method sends a Status Code 300 to the browser which directs the user to a new page. What you want to do is create a `WebRequest` and parse the response:

```
string url = string.Format("www.insuranceini.com/insurance.asp?fileno1={0}", txtfileno1);
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string urlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

EDIT: I wrapped the WebResponse and StreamReader objects in using statements so they are disposed of properly once you're finished with them.

Comment: Ok let me try that..thanks!so for example if my insurance.aspx has about 5 parameters txtfileno1, txtfileno2, username, userid,dteinsured   how will that appear in the url that you have mentioned above?

Comment: I'm using the `string.Format` method. So with multiple parameters, your could do: `string.Format("www.insuranceini.com/insurance.aspx?txtfileno1={0}&txtfileno2={1}&username={2}&userid={3}&dteinsured={4}", txtfileno1, txtfileno2, username, userid, dteinsured)`, where everything outside of the string is a variable.