# Web Service capture Response

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httpwebrequest, asmx

My web service calls a url which returns a value which I must capture and use in a different function.

I've only recently starting working with web services and am very new to the concept of calling a url within a web service *(Previously asked and answered on this forum for those requiring more information)*

[Webservice method to call a url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12378568/1270384)

My web service is: Insurance Service.

My client sends me data through the Insurance service which calls a url which returns an Insurance Number.

How do I capture this insurance number? I thought I could use session to capture it but I was so wrong insurance Number comes as null with an object reference error.

```
int insuranceNo;
insuranceNo = Convert.ToInt16(HttpContext.Current.Session["insuranceNo"]);
```

It must have something to do with response right?

I thought I could try google what I am looking for but I honestly don't know what to call this in order to search for it. Thought I'd give it another shot in this forum since I found the answer to the first part of this function here.

code to call url:

```
 string url = string.Format("www.insuranceini.com/insurance.asp?fileno1={0},&txtfileno2={1‌​}&username={2}&userid={3}&dteinsured={4}&dteDob={5}&InsurerName={6}", txtfileno1, txtfileno2, username, userid, dteinsured,dteDob,InsurerName)
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string urlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any sort of pointers or places to start looking or any advice.

Comment: What kind of data does the web service return?  XML/JSON or something else?     If its just url parameters like your example, try browsing it in your web browser and see what response you get.  Or use something like Fiddler that lets you look at the HTTP response.

Comment: Yeah unless your Webservice explicitly sets it as a session you wont find it there. If its a JSON body you will need to parse it into an object your code can read, same for xml.

Comment: Well it should return in xml format but right now everything crashes at the place where I am initialising my insuranceNo because I'm pretty sure insurance number isn't/shouldn't be captured as a session.

Comment: well thank you for that but thats exactly what I am asking, how do I do that?

Comment: What is the result after the `ReadToEnd`?

Comment: code doesn't reach there as it is stuck at the initilising of InsuranceNo as mentioned above, the previous users suggest parsing it into the object code but I don't know how to do that. Any sort of clarification on what was advised earlier or anything to get my code going into the httprequest would be great

Comment: What leads you to believe that the insuranceNo would be available in Session? Have you tried running just the lower code sample?

Comment: Good Question @PHeiberg let me try that.

Comment: I get the error in : http://stackoverflow.com/q/12417770/1270384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code began giving different errors. Closing this and referring to : [Datetime Conversion and Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12417770/1270384)

Thank you everyone for the helpful comments.